# Can only access one of the two Samba shared directories

Tags: linux, samba

I have a linux server that I am using to share various directories with Samba. I have two directories setup to share in my smb.conf, but I can only access one.

***Why does one work while the other doesn't if they have the same settings? What other variable am I not accounting for?***

My smb.conf is below. Note that newtest works but test does not work.

```
[global]
    security = SHARE
    map to guest = bad user

[test]

  path = /home/Administrator/test
  browsable = yes
  writable = yes
  guest ok = yes
  read only = no

[newtest]

  path = /opt/vmpro/test
  browsable = yes
  writable = yes
  guest ok = yes
  read only = no
```

**As mentioned, test fails..**

[image]

**But newtest works...**

[image]

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I'm facing an issue that seems similar to yours.

Answer (score 0):

You can try add permisions to "/home/Administrator/test" with **chmod**

```
sudo chmod 777 /home/Administrator/test
```